# What elements can change in the ending?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've read, while I was researching for the memories, that having all 13 memories adds a scene to the ending.

That means to me that the ending can be variable depending on what you did/skipped.

What elements of the ending can change, and the change depends on what?

PS: This is kind of a question of "What are the different endings, and how to I reach them?", but it doesn't seem that there are massive changes to the ending depending on what is done (A main character wont die, or turn on you, etc.). So thats why I'm asking more on a modular kind of way.

Damn I think I'm confusing. Am I clear on what am I asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is only the bad ending (not getting all of the memories) and the good ending (getting all of the memories).

There is not much to the main story besides:

- Recover Memories
- Recover the Divine Beasts
- > Kill Ganon

The only thing the Divine Beasts seem to affect is

> the hp of Ganon and whether or not you have to do a "boss rush"

As for what actually changes in the ending... if you do not recover all the memories:

> After beating Ganon, Zelda will say "but do you really remember who I am?"

If you collect all of the memories:

> The same cutscene as above will play, but with more to it afterwards: Zelda will talk about going to Zora's Domain to talk to Mipha's father about her, due to the Divine Beast malfunctioning. Zelda talks about her power dwindling over the last 100 years. The camera fades out on a Silent Princess [I believe] flower.

Really, the "true ending" is overall pretty meh, but it's something.

Comment: And so, what changes between both endings?

Comment: @Fredy31 added.